# How to determine yaw angle from GPS bearing?

Tags: ros, gps, coordinate-system

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I determine yaw angle if I know bearing angle from GPS?

The GPS I have can output bearing, which is the angle direction from point1 (at time1) to point2 (at time2). The bearing I have is equal to what I got using this website: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

My question is how can I find yaw angle given this bearing? for both NED and ENU.

Thank you very much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219182/how-to-determine-yaw-angle-from-gps-bearing?/) by [fujisan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24524/fujisan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I hope you have a solution by now, but the bearing angle should be the same as the yaw angle in NED.

For ENU, the polarity of the angle is reversed, and is offset by 90 degrees.  Therefore, to convert bearing 'b' to yaw angle 'y':

y = 90 - b

Don't forget to convert to radians!

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0